# How to enable hash algorithm SHA-256 for ASP.NET, .NET Framework 4.8?

Tags: asp.net, sha256, wse

We have a web service, running under Windows 2019 Server. It's implemented with C# (WSE 2.0, ASP.NET, .NET Framework 4.8).

That web service needs data from another web service. So for every request a SOAP request message is created and sent to that other web service.

That interface to that other web service has been changed. Before that change the SOAP response messages contained no security header at all. Now they contain such a security header and the signatures are encrypted with SHA-256. This causes error messages: "SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm supplied."

In outgoing SOAP request messages I see that SHA-1 is used for the signatures.

So obvious the system is no able to handle SHA-256 and I have to adapt it.

I've added a public class RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription to the code, with overriding methods for CreateDeformatter and CreateFormatter and a method to register the sha-256 hash algorithm which is called in constructor of proxy class for that interface to the other web service.

The signature algorithm of the signature object is set to SHA-256, too.

The Cryptographic Service Provider of the client certificate for that interface was set to "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider". She signature algorithm of the certificate is sha256.

Some entries in the Windows registry have been added:
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Hashes\SHA256, set to enabled
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Configuration\Local\Default\Functions\Hashes\SHA256 = bcrypt.dll
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Configuration\Local\Default\Providers\Hash\SHA256\Functions\OpenSSL = bcrypt.dll

In files C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config and
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
entries have been created for mscorlib and cryptoClass RSASHA256SignatureDescription.

None of that changes had any effect. The SOAP request messages for the other web service are still signed with SHA-1 and the incomming response messages cannot be processed.

So whether I made a mistake or there is still any importand configuration missing.

Does anyone have an idea how the using of hash algorithm SHA-256 can be enabled?

Comment: The question is unclear because everything you ask works out of the box. In fact, SOAP was created by Microsoft. WSE was created by Microsoft before getting replaced by the WS-* standard. Microsoft that pushed for WS-* and WCF implemented them natively. All .NET versions supported SHA256

Comment: The real problem is that WSE is beyond dead. WSE 2 was released in 2004 and replaced by WS# 3.0 in 2005. It was completely replaced by WCF in 2008, which supported the new (then) standards. What is the *real* problem here? Why are you using a non-standard technology that died 20 years ago? If you want to talk to an ASMX service the *correct* way is to go to the `Add Service Reference` dialog and click on the `Add Web Reference` button.

Comment: Yes, I've also read, that with .NET framework 4.8 SHA-256 is used as default. So in fact my question is: Why it does NOT work out of the box in this case?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a service that doesn't follow the SOAP standards perhaps? That's the case eg with Sabre and other corporations that implemented specifications that didn't become part of the SOAP or WS-* standards, eg BPEL. WCF is stricter about standards compliance than ASMX. Once again you can use `Add Web Reference` to create an old-style client. There's no issue with SHA256, I've been calling Sabre services for the last 10 years.

Comment: `with .NET framework 4.8 SHA-256 is used as default.` wrong  - all .NET versions supported this. If you check the [Sha256 class docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256?view=net-8.0) they go back to .NET 1.1. `Why it does NOT work` because you're trying to use a library and spec that died 20 years ago, whose code was never updated to handle SHA256 because it just wasn't needed in 2004. .NET Framework 2.0 came out in 2005, along with WSE *3.0*.

Comment: Yes, WSE 2.0 is old. But this is the situation I have to handle. It would be a big effort to rewrite the code completely to use a more modern web service functionality.

Comment: Then you have to rewrite. The service you try to call abandoned it and won't work even if you change the hashing algorithm. This isn't just a settings change. As the Wikipedia article says about WSE 2.0 `It is also compatible with .NET 2.0, however it does not have design time support with Visual Studio 2005. It is not interoperable with WSE 3.0 and WCF.` As for `a more modern` even WSE 3.0 is 19 years old

Comment: But the old web service works in general - the only problem is this with SHA-256 in the response messages.

Comment: No, the only problem is that you're trying to affect 20-year old binaries that were built to be thrown away in 1 year (MS already knew that WSE 3 was coming when it released WSE 2 and actually said so in conferences) that don't even use the settings you're trying to tweak. You'll have to find the old documentation if it's even available to see whether you can change hash algorithm at all.

Comment: If you want to keep working with WSE 2.0, check the [docs at MS Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/aa338214(v=vs.71)) to find out how configuration works. Configuration in .NET never used the registry. It always used XML configuration files

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.